# Translations not working in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, twig, xliff, symfony-2.6

I have a file with french translations located in `FooBundle/Resources/translations/messages.fr.xlf`

Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xliff version="1.2" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2">
    <file source-language="en" datatype="plaintext" original="file.ext">
        <body>
            <trans-unit id="1">
                <source>Foo</source>
                <target>Bar</target>
            </trans-unit>
        </body>
    </file>
</xliff>
```

But I can't seem to make any translation work, neither in the controller:

```
// FooBundle/Controller/DefaultController.php
/**
 * @Route("/")
 * @Template()
 */
public function indexAction(Request $request)
{
    $request->setLocale("fr");
    $translatedMessage = $this->get('translator')->trans('Foo');

    echo $translatedMessage;

    return array();
}
```

Or the twig template:

```
// FooBundle/Resources/views/Default/index.html.twig
{{ 'Foo'|trans }} or {% trans %}Foo{% endtrans %}
```

It always shows `Foo` (the original string).

As my default locale I use english ('en'). My locale config from `config.yml`:

```
framework:
    translator: { fallback: "%locale%" }
    default_locale: "%locale%"
    ...
```

I've tried to clean up the cache but it didn't make any difference.

If I try to debug the translations, it shows that they are being used:

```
$ php app/console debug:translation fr FooBundle

+----------+---------------+----------------------+
| State(s) | Id            | Message Preview (fr) |
+----------+---------------+----------------------+
|          | Foo           | Bar                  |
+----------+---------------+----------------------+
```

Any idea what is going wrong here?

Comment: Just tested with your code without modification (Symfony 2.6.3) and it works without problem. Try to output the settings of the framework bundle and check that everything related to the translator service is OK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the problem was another bundle I have installed (LuneticsLocaleBundle).

Somehow it must override the `$request->setLocale("fr");` I do in the controller so it turns out I was using `en_US` as locale. That was the reason why it wasn't showing the translations.